# Error with GR8 CRM Core Plugin does not compile

Tags: grails, plugins, groovy, crm

I can not use the GR8 CRM Core Plugin due to an error that I can not solve.

Added the plugin in buildconfig.groogy (compile ': crm-core: 2.0.2') and its dependencies (compile ": twitter-bootstrap: 2.3.2" compile ": less-resources: 1.3.3.2") as mentioned in your [tutorial](http://gr8crm.github.io/tutorials/gr8crm-web/index.html).

but when compiling the following error occurs:

```
|Packaging Grails application
....
|Compiling 251 source files
Adding tenantId field to class grails.plugins.crm.core.CrmLookupEntity
.Error 
|
Compilation error: startup failed:
C:\appMock\target\work\plugins\crm-core-2.0.0\src\groovy\grails\plugins\crm\core\ClosureDelegate.groovy: 33: [Static type checking] - Cannot statically compile constructor implicitly including non static elements from object initializers, properties or fields.
 @ line 33, column 5.
       @CompileStatic
       ^

C:\appMock\target\work\plugins\crm-core-2.0.0\src\groovy\grails\plugins\crm\core\ClosureToMap.groovy: 34: [Static type checking] - Cannot statically compile constructor implicitly including non static elements from object initializers, properties or fields.
 @ line 34, column 5.
       @CompileStatic
       ^

C:\appMock\target\work\plugins\crm-core-2.0.0\src\groovy\grails\plugins\crm\util\Graph.groovy: 98: [Static type checking] - Cannot return value of type java.util.Collection <grails.plugins.crm.util.Vertex> on method returning type java.util.List <Vertex>
 @ line 98, column 9.
           vList.findAll { Vertex v -> !eList.find { Edge e -> v == e.source } }
           ^

3 errors


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I can not any reference about why these errors. I tried changing the version of the plugin to an older and continued the same mistake.

I'm using Grails 2.3.7 and Groovy 2.4.0 and the Java JDK 1.7

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to download a previous version of grails.

http://gr8crm.github.io/tutorials/gr8crm-web/index.html#_prerequisites

- GR8 CRM plugins are not tested with Grails versions above 2.2.4, so please make sure you have Grails 2.2.4 installed and ready before you attempt to follow this guide.

I got the content tutorial to work with Grails 2.2.5, if figured that wasn't too risky.

some changes different were to BuildConfig.groovy:

> ```
>   runtime ":hibernate:2.2.4"
>   runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
> ```

This was only the "content" demo.

Had to do it from the command line cause the IDE puts stupid stuff in the workspace. I'd imagine if I wanted to fight it long enough I'd figured it out. But wanted to get the demo going.

Take a look at the github branch m4-greach. It says works with "Upgraded to Grails 2.4.5"

https://github.com/gr8crm/gr8contact/tree/m4-greach